# Compile Multiple hash.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can have any advice to compile the multiple `window.location.hash` in a short script? I ask because it seems like now I'm repeating the hash.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).on('hashchange load',function()
{
    if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash == '#home') {
        console.log('home load');
    } else if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash == '#about') {
        console.log('about load');
    } else if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash == '#contact') {
        console.log('contact load');
    }
});
```

Comment: this is pos off-topic here and better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as the code works

Comment: though, my advice is, they all check `window.location.hash` - why not have one if statement for that then a switch for the value (e.g. `if (window.location.hash) {//switch statement here}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is quite vague, but given the current code, it could be shortened by taking the value of `window.location.hash`, removing the hashtag (i.e. `#`) and appending `load` to that string.

See a demonstration below

```js
$(window).on('hashchange load', function() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var hashValue = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    console.log(hashValue + ' load');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="home"></a>
<a name="about"></a>
<a name="other"></a>
<div>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#other">Other</a>
</div>
```

If you need to restrict the values, you could declare a array of predefined values in `pages` using [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). One could also use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and then not need to check if the value is greater than negative one, but be aware of [the browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility).

```js
var pages = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];
$(window).on('hashchange load', function() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var hashValue = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if (pages.indexOf(hashValue) > -1) {
      console.log(hashValue + ' load');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="home"></a>
<a name="about"></a>
<a name="other"></a>
<div>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#other">Other</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's not much that can be done to shorten the code. To make it flow better there are a couple of tweaks though. Firstly you can move the `window.location.hash` value check to its own condition to save repeating it. Then you can check each value:

```
$(window).on('hashchange load', function() {
  if (!window.location.hash)
    return;

  if (window.location.hash == '#home') {
    console.log('home load');
  } else if (window.location.hash == '#about') {
    console.log('about load'); 
  } else if (window.location.hash == '#contact') {
    console.log('contact load');
  }
});
```

To expand this further to make the logic more extensible you could store the functions to be executed under those hash changes within an object, keyed by the hash value itself, something like this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange load', function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if (hash && functions.hasOwnProperty(hash))
      functions[hash]();
}); 

var functions = {
  '#home': function() {
    console.log('home load');
  },
  '#about': function() {
    console.log('about load');
  },
  '#contact': function() {
    console.log('contact load');
  }
}
```

While this method isn't technically 'shorter', it's far more extensible.

Comment: I like the functions thing -- would it be better to use .substr to get everything after the `#` - just for better-reading purposes...

Comment: Certainly possible, although a more stylistic choice.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no need to validate the hash each time

And in terms of performance, it is better save a new hash reference like

```
let hash = this.location.hash;
```

And access the hash each time vs this.location.hash is less expensive

```
$(window).on('hashchange load',function() {  
    // this validation for existence of hash can be done only once
    let hash = this.location.hash;

    if(!hash) {
        return;
    }

    if(hash == '#home') { 
        console.log('home load');
    } else if(hash == '#about') {
        console.log('about load');
    }
});
```